# How to plot a ROC curve by varying a parameter in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, python-3.6

I am trying to plot multiple ROC curves on a plot by varying a variable in a cell in a pandas dataframe. [image]

So in a particular row, if the total is above a certain threshold then it will be classified as an invoice. I want to be plotting the different curves on different thresholds of total.

This is the code that I have so far that measures basic metrics and is an attempt to plot the ROC curve but I have been unsuccessful so far.

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import datasets, metrics, model_selection, svm
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import scikitplot as skplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("test_results.csv", header = 0)
true_array = list(df["actual"].to_numpy())
predicted_array = list(df["predicted"].to_numpy())

accuracy  = accuracy_score(true_array, predicted_array)
precision, recall, fscore, support = score(true_array, predicted_array, average = None, labels = ['invoice', 'non-invoice'])

print("Labels: \t invoice", "non-invoice")
print('Accuracy: \t {}'.format(accuracy))
print('Precision: \t {}'.format(precision))
print('Recall: \t {}'.format(recall))
print('Fscore: \t {}'.format(fscore))

skplt.metrics.plot_roc_curve(true_array, predicted_array)
plt.show()
```

The error I am getting is

fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_true, probas[:, i],
IndexError: too many indices for array

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The following documentation mentions that skplt.metrics.plot_roc_curve takes ground truth (correct) target values and prediction probabilities for each class returned by a classifier. So you should change 2nd input prediction_array.

https://scikit-plot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metrics.html?highlight=roc#scikitplot.metrics.plot_roc